# I can't add a using reference on my C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Beta2 and I can't add a reference to:
*system.drawing*

I've tried right click on the solution explorer but I can't find it there.

What gives?

Answer (score 3):

Here is all you need to do in VS 2010:

1. In `Solution Explorer` right click on the `References` folder of your project
2. Select `Add Reference`.
3. Under the `Assemblies` category there is a sub category of `Framework`.  If that is selected you should see a list of all of the Microsoft .NET Framework libraries
4. Find `System.Drawing` and double click it.

Then your project will have the reference added to it!

Answer (score 2):

In VS2010 Beta 2 the references list may not be automatically sorted because it loads asynchronously. You may need to wait for it to finish loading then click the column header to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Solution explorer is for adding references to external libraries.

It sounds like you just want to add the line

```
using System.Drawing;
```

to the top of one particular file.